# Formula works in excel but not in vba

Tags: vba, excel

the below formula works in a cell, but when I try to use it in VBA it gives syntax error. Why is it and what is the solution?. Thanks.

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(Lastrow + 1, 9).Formula = "=(SUMIFS(Sheet1!$B:$B,Sheet1!$O:$O,">0")/SUM(Sheet1!$B1:$B1000))*100"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is with `">0"` to use quotations inside a `String` you need to do the following:

`"">0""` with double quotations VBA understands its a `String` inside the `String`.
 instead of the end `"` of the `String` `>0` some code and `"` the start of a new `String`.

Answer (score -1):

You need to use single quotes for the string otherwise the string ends and will throw an error but there may be something else going on. What is your exact error?

Comment: Excel formulas do not understand single quotes; e.g. `'`. The double-quotes need to be doubled up as *'quotes within a quoted string'*.

Comment: You've edited your answer but it still states that you need to use singles quotes. This is incorrect just as Jeeped mention. See my answer for the correct way.

Comment: You are right.  I don't know why I thought that would work.  I know I program in something where I do that.  Not vba apparently sorry. I was wrong.